# Attachment to the message by email (attachment)

Tags: .net, vb.net

would anyone be able to help attach a photo to an email?

```
imports System.IO
imports System.Net
imports System.Net.Mail
imports System.Drawing.Imaging

 Private Sub Timer2_Tick(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Timer2.Tick
    Try
        Dim MyMailMessage As New MailMessage()
        MyMailMessage.From = New MailAddress("@gmail.com")
        MyMailMessage.To.Add("@gmail.com")
        MyMailMessage.Subject = ("New message!")
        MyMailMessage.Body = RichTextBox1.Text
        Dim SMTPServer As New SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com")
        SMTPServer.Port = 587
        SMTPServer.Credentials = New System.Net.NetworkCredential("@gmail.com", "password")
        SMTPServer.EnableSsl = True
        SMTPServer.Send(MyMailMessage)
        RichTextBox1.Text = ("")
    Catch ex As Exception
    End Try
End Sub

Private Sub Timer3_Tick(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Timer3.Tick
    Dim screenshot As Bitmap = New Bitmap(Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Width, Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Height, PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb)
    Dim screenshotGraphics As Graphics = Graphics.FromImage(screenshot)
    screenshotGraphics.CopyFromScreen(Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.X, Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Y, 0, 0, Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Size, CopyPixelOperation.SourceCopy)
    screenshot.Save("C:\...\...\img.png", System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png)
End Sub
```

timer2 is set to 2 hours

timer3 is set to 10 min

So it would be possible to send photos taken every 10 minutes to a message sent every 2 hours?

Comment: Guessing something like `MyMailMessage.Attachments.Add(...)`

Comment: Yes, but, then it pops up: 'screenshot is not declared. It may be inaccessible due to its protection level. I would then have to add the code from timer3 to timer2

Comment: No, you want to declare `Dim screenshot As Bitmap` outside Timer3 method, so its a member variable and you'll declare it like this: `Private screenshot As Bitmap`

Comment: Just an idea, assumming I'm getting your intentions here.  Save the screenshots to a standard location in timer3.  Then in timer2, search that location for any png files and attach them to the email.  Saves having public references floating around

Comment: The documentation for the `MailMessage` class includes a code example that adds an attachment. You should NEVER be posting a question here without having read the relevant documentation first. If you have tried to use code that adds an attachment and it didn't work then you should be showing us that code and explaining what actually happened.

Comment: Could you show an example?

Comment: Why would you need an example of declaring a variable?